# Установить значение атрибута lang html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Как в react установить значение у атрибута lang у тега html? По умолчанию он есть и содержит `en`.

Comment: Посмотрите тут, вроде ваша тема https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237420/manipulate-the-html-or-body-tag-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(()=> {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang','rusafasdw') // или querySelector()
},[])
```

это не зона деятельности реакт просто обычный js

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в директории public лежит html файл в котором написан язык - отредактируйте его
или
Воспользуйтесь пакетом React helmet
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet